# PHP setcookie function including samesite parameter does not work

Tags: php, setcookie, samesite

I have a fully working `setcookie()` php function running using these params...

```php
<?php

setcookie(
  '_siteauth', 
  Crypt::encrypt(site()->password),
  time() + 86400,
  '/',
);

?>
```

The code above sets a cookie everytime with no issues!

But as soon as I attempt to use `samesite` option the cookie never sets... which is a problem.

I am not running this in a iFrame. I am testing this locally using dockers wordpress image, which I cant see being a problem.

At first after all the online reading, I thought it might be a PHP version conflict, but it failed to work in either tests pre/post PHP version 7.3.0.

After reading https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

...it says options can be set as associative array including `expires`, `path`, `domain`, `secure`, `httponly` and `samesite`, but everytime I try this php setcookie method it does not set.

This is my locally dumped `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` result...

```txt
demo.local.mydomain.com
```

Here are all my local tested code attempts, using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` for domain...

```php
<?php

setcookie(
    '_siteauth',
    Crypt::encrypt(site()->password), 
    [
        'expires' => time() + 86400,
        'path' => '/',
        'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        'samesite' => 'None',
        'secure' => false,
        'httponly' => false
    ]
);

?>
```

```php
<?php

setcookie(
    '_siteauth',
    Crypt::encrypt(site()->password),
    time() + 86400,
    '/; SameSite=none'
);

?>
```

```php
<?php

setcookie(
    '_siteauth',
    Crypt::encrypt(site()->password),
    [
        'expires' => time() + 86400,
        'path' => '/',
        'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        'secure' => false,
        'httponly' => false,
        'samesite' => 'None'
    ]
);

?>
```

And none of these code examples save the `_siteauth` cookie when executed.

I've tried every variation of php version `setcookie()` including the `samesite` key and value but no cookie is saved.

The reason I am changing my previous `setcookie()` script is because there was a change early in 2020 in chrome with iframe cookie policies, defaulting to samesite `Lax`. So I need to force samesite `None` when setting my cookie.

https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/ 
https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/

If anyone can see where I'm going wrong, help would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a cookie with `SameSite=None` it'll be blocked (by the browser) unless it also has `Secure`, which is omitted/set to false in the code snippets.

```php
setcookie(
    '_siteauth',
    Crypt::encrypt(site()->password), 
    [
        'expires' => time() + 86400,
        'path' => '/',
        'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
        'samesite' => 'None',
        'secure' => true,
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks a million dude!!! It doesn't work locally, however your answer fixes my staging and production environment issues. I can work with this :-) Thank you for taking the time to help... saved me hours of attempting to debug.

Comment: If you've read docs that say `SameSite=None` must be `Secure=true`, please share so I can see what I missed thanks.

Comment: @joshmoto In the MDN page for Set-Cookie https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#fixing_common_warnings